# Ayuda en Mongoose y mongoDB con consultas enlazadas

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy pasando una query que hice y funciona en mongoDB a mongoose y me da error.

La consulta en mongo DB es:

```js
db.facturas.find({
    _id: {$in: db.detalles.distinct("id_factura",{category: ObjectId("5889eae21ffcc6da2c6b4ae4")})}
})
```

El objectId de category es un parametro en la APP de nodeJS

En la APP he armado la query asi:

```js
    Factura.find({'_id': {"$in": Detalle.distinct("id_factura",{qrycat})}})
    .populate('pto_venta')
    .populate('forma_pago')
    .exec(function(err, result) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json(result); 
    });
```

Y me da el siguiente error en NODEJS:

> /var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:242
>    var body = JSON.stringify(val, replacer, spaces);
>                   ^
>
> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>      at Object.stringify (native)
>      at ServerResponse.json (/var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:242:19)
>      at ServerResponse.send (/var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:151:21)
>      at /var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/app/handlers/facturasHandler.js:494:22
>      at /var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2176:21
>      at /var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/kareem/index.js:160:11
>      at Query._find (/var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1019:5)
>      at /var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/kareem/index.js:156:8
>      at /var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/kareem/index.js:18:7
>      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
>   events.js:160
>        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>        ^
>
> Error: read ECONNRESET
>      at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
>      at Pipe.onread (net.js:568:26)

Comment: Tu objetivo es hacer una relación entre dos colecciones? (sí, se puede)

Comment: @J.Correa La idea es trae las facturas de acuerdo al array que me devuelve: Detalle.distinct("id_factura",{qrycat}).
Donde qrycat son filtros.